# Developer tools styling for chrome 34 version

Tags: google-chrome

I had found earlier css files so I could customize the style of developer tools. But after some update, it stopped working. So those files might be in different place. Maybe someone knows how can I customize on this version?

I want actually on hover to highlight the line in console - its easier to see in which line number the errors happen.